# Gradle error for java library module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android Studio project, there are 2 modules: an android app module and a java library module, they all worked. But after I upgraded the Android Studio and Gradle, the java library module doesn't work.

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0.
 Required by:
     :demo:unspecified
  > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0 available for  offline mode.
```

If there is no com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0 in my Android Studio, why the android app module works normally?

Comment: Post code build.gradle (Project: NameProject)

Comment: You are working offline. The gradle plugin requires the internet connection at least one time

Comment: I know it, but why the app module can work in offline mode. My Android Studio is not permitted to connect the Internet, so I wonder where can I get the gradle plugin for Android Studio(not gradle itself) and install it manually?

Comment: I have the same problem